# how to keep `hapi` running if remote server not available

Tags: hapi.js

**Update:** Oh well, it was as easy as wrapping the `Wreck.get()` call in a `try… catch` block. No further action is needed on this question.

I am requesting data from a remote server using the following simple code

```
const {res, payload} =  await Wreck.get(uri);
```

If, for some reason, the remote server is unreachable (network down, someone unplugged the router, whatever), `hapijs` (version 17) quits with a fatal error

```
{ Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND remote.org remote.org:443
    at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.onlookup [as oncomplete] (dns.js:57:26)
errno: 'ENOTFOUND',
code: 'ENOTFOUND',
syscall: 'getaddrinfo',
hostname: 'remote.org',
host: 'remote.org',
port: 443,
trace:
[ { method: 'GET',
    url:
        'https://remote.org/api/…' } ],
isBoom: true,
isServer: true,
data: null,
output:
{ statusCode: 502,
    payload:
    { message:
        'Client request error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND remote.org remote.org:443',
        statusCode: 502,
        error: 'Bad Gateway' },
    headers: {} },
reformat: [Function] }
```

I would rather that error message is return but `hapijs` keeps on running. How do I do that?

Comment: Please add your edit as an answer then accept it so this question won't appear unsolved anymore.

Answer (score 0):

Adding a `try {} catch(err) {}` block around the `Wreck.get()` statement solved the problem.